# How can i get attribute option id in controller?

Tags: magento2

I try in my controller in following way

```
$newOption = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Option\Collection')
                         ->setPositionOrder('asc')
                         ->setAttributeFilter($attributeId)
                         ->setStoreFilter($storeId)->getItemByColumnValue("value", $data['title']);

            print_r($newOption['option_id']);exit;
```

Comment: and what happens when you try this?

Comment: Showing Blank page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When instantiating a collection and filtering through it, you will always get a set of results back.
you can try this after your code:

```
$newOption = $newOption->getFirstItem();
```

also, don't use the `_objectManager` in a controller. It works, but it's not a best practice.
You should inject in the constructor of your controller an instance of `Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Option\CollectionFactory` and use that one.

something like this:

```
protected $optionCollectionFactory;
public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Option\CollectionFactory $optionCollectionFactory,
    ....
){
    ....
    $this->optionCollectionFactory = $optionCollectionFactory;
}
```

then use this in your code:

```
$options = $this->optionCollectionFactory->create()
                         ->setPositionOrder('asc')
                         ->setAttributeFilter($attributeId)
                         ->setStoreFilter($storeId)->getItemByColumnValue("value", $data['title']);

$newOption = $options->getFirstItem();

print_r($newOption->getOptionId());exit;
```

Comment: Hello Marius i add your code in my controller i get following error Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to RB\Modulename\Controller\Adminhtml\Manage\Save::__construct() must be an instance of RB\Modulename \Controller\Adminhtml\Manage\Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Option\CollectionFactory, instance of Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context given, called in E:\wamp\www\magento2.1\var\generation\RB\Modulename \Controller\Adminhtml\Manage\Save\Interceptor.php on line 14 and defined in E:\wamp\www\magento2.1\app\code\RB\Modulename \Controller\Adminhtml\Manage\Save.php on line 17

Comment: clear the contents of `var/generation`

Comment: Class RB\Modulename\Controller\Adminhtml\Manage\Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Option\CollectionFactory does not exist

Comment: @Pratik. Oups. Forgot a `\\` in the constructor parameter. Try again.

Comment: yes you are right thx for help. after everyrthing done i found this error Fatal error: Call to a member function isLoggedIn() on a non-object in E:\wamp\www\magento2.1\vendor\magento\module-backend\App\AbstractAction.php on line 252

Comment: that's a totally different issue. Not sure about this one, where it comes from or why.